# Jenkins pipeline post always step doesn't execute on failing build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline which runs just fine when the build status is successful.

However when the UI tests fail and the build status is set to failed all the code in the post always step is ignored.

I have checked if maybe the test report is not created in case of test failures but these are present on the specified location.

I have no idea why Jenkins won't run the post always step in case of a failing build.

I expect the post always step to be run in both a failed or success scenario, can anyone explain to me why it doesn't?

```
        post {
        always {
                node('master') {
                    dir('/appl/jenkins/test/workspace/pipeline/test-reports') {
                        unstash 'test-report'

                        // This plugin script replaces the hard coded D:\ drive references with the path of the Jenkins job
                        // in order to make screenshot links function OK in the Jenkins copy of the HTML report.

                        //TODO add build number to report to identify test run.
                        echo 'Run completed before script block'

                        script {
                            contentReplace(
                                    configs: [
                                            fileContentReplaceConfig(
                                                    configs: [
                                                            fileContentReplaceItemConfig(
                                                                    search: 'original_path',
                                                                    replace: 'replaced_path',
                                                                    matchCount: 0)
                                                    ],
                                                    fileEncoding: 'UTF-8',
                                                    filePath: '/appl/jenkins/test/workspace/pipeline/test-reports/report.html')
                                    ])
                        }

                        echo 'Run completed after script block'

                        // Below we use the Publish HTML plugin to publish the report.html resulting from the Extend Reports plugin.
                        publishHTML target: [
                                allowMissing         : false,
                                alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                                keepAll              : true,
                                reportDir            : '/appl/jenkins/test/workspace/pipeline/test-reports',
                                reportFiles          : 'report.html, *.png',
                                reportName           : 'Extent Report deluxe (screenshots!)'
                        ]

                        echo 'Run completed after publish block'

                        //deleteDir() /* clean up Master workspace */
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: is this a `scripted pipeline` or `Declarative` pipeline

Comment: Hi Gaurang, this is concerning a declarative pipeline.

Comment: can you try `echo "always"` before `node('master')` and see if you get this message in logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the post always step directly to the end of the test step in my pipeline instead of the absolute end of my pipeline and now it works.

I think this is a bug in the pipeline mechanism of Jenkins, else I would expect the post step never to have run instead of just on a success scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure while building "propagate" is not set to true, if it is then change it to propagate: false